# How do I use nested Templates from a constant string variable in Go?

Tags: go, go-templates

I have been trying to use nested templates in Go, however the Examples or help documents are not helping me, and examples in 3 other blogs are not what I'm looking for (one is close and maybe the only way but I want to make sure)

OK, so my code is for App Engine, in here I will be doing an `urlfetch` to a server, and then I want to show some results, like the `Response`, headers, and body.

```
const statusTemplate = `
{{define "RT"}}
Status      - {{.Status}}
Proto       - {{.Proto}}
{{end}}
{{define "HT"}}
{{range $key, $val := .}}
{{$key}} - {{$val}}
{{end}}
{{end}}
{{define "BT"}}
{{.}}
{{end}}
{{define "MT"}}
<html>
    <body>
        <pre>
-- Response --
{{template "RT"}}

--  Header  --
{{template "HT"}}

--   Body   --
{{template "BT"}}
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
{{end}}
{{template "MT"}}`

func showStatus(w http.ResponseWriterm r *http.Request) {
    /*
     *  code to get:
     *  resp as http.Response
     *  header as a map with the header values
     *  body as an string wit the contents
     */
    t := template.Must(template.New("status").Parse(statusTemplate)
    t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "RT", resp)
    t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "HT", header)
    t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "BT", body)
    t.Execute(w, nil)
}
```

My code actually outputs the RT, HT, and BT templates with the correct values, and then it outputs the MT template empty (MT stands for main template).

So... How can I use nested forms from a string variable so that an example as the above works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the approach you try with nested templates is wrong. If you want `.` to be defined inside a nested template, you have to supply an argument to the call to the nested template, just as you do with the `ExecuteTemplate` function:

```
{{define "RT"}}
Status      - {{.Status}}
Proto       - {{.Proto}}
{{end}}
{{define "HT"}}
{{range $key, $val := .}}
{{$key}} - {{$val}}
{{end}}
{{end}}
{{define "BT"}}
{{.}}
{{end}}
{{define "MT"}}
<html>
    <body>
        <pre>
-- Response --
{{template "RT" .Resp}}

--  Header  --
{{template "HT" .Header}}

--   Body   --
{{template "BT" .Body}}
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
{{end}}
{{template "MT"}}
```

The important part you seem to miss is that templates *do not* encapsulate state. When you execute a template, the engine evaluates the template for the given argument and then writes out the generated text. It does not save the argument or anything that was generated for future invocations.

### Documentation

Relevant part of the [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template):

> #### Actions
>
> Here is the list of actions. "Arguments" and "pipelines" are
>   evaluations of data, defined in detail below.
>
> ```
> ...
>
> {{template "name"}}
>   The template with the specified name is executed with nil data.
>
> {{template "name" pipeline}}
>   The template with the specified name is executed with dot set
>   to the value of the pipeline.
>
> ...
> ```

I hope this clears up things.

Comment: So what I should be doing is change my template as you suggested, and make a map|structure to send in those values? if that's the case, would I need to `{{template "MT" .}}`?

Comment: @Goodwine Not quite; in the example code you gave, you create a template "status" that calls "MT" with nil data. You defined MT as a subtemplate; just use ExecuteTemplate(w,"MT",data) instead (or use {{template "MT" .}}).

Comment: I am using `{{template "MT" .}}` tho

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this tutorial:
http://javatogo.blogspot.com

there it is explained how to use nested templates.

Comment: Oh~ I haven't stumbled upon this blog post, it is not exactly what I wanted tho, because it's separating the templates, and the Go documents say that I should be able to do what I am trying to.